# Error Cannot call 'crossunder' with arguments (plot, plot); available overloads: crossunder(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool];

Tags: pine-script

Hello I added these lines to the [Resampling Reverse Engineering Bands [DW]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/pK0AIDt2-Resampling-Reverse-Engineering-Bands-DW/) script :

```
a = plot (close, color = color.white, transp = 100, title = "close") 

plotshape(crossover(a,mplot), style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar,size=size.tiny)
plotshape(crossunder(a,mplot), style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar,size=size.tiny)

alertcondition(crossover(a,mplot),title="Close Crossover")
alertcondition(crossunder(a,mplot),title="Close Crossunder")
```

The idea is that when this plot (a =) cross (mplot =) I have an alert.
But I get this error code: `Cannot Cannot call 'crossunder' with arguments (plot, plot); available overloads: crossunder(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool];`

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the plot objects in the `crossover()` function.
You have to use the values they represent.

Plot `a` represents the value of `close`.
Plot `mplot` represents the value of `mband`.

So you'll have to change your code to:

```
a = plot(close, color = color.white, transp = 100, title = "close") 

plotshape(crossover(close,  mband), style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(crossunder(close, mband), style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny)

alertcondition(crossover(close,  mband), title="Close Crossover")
alertcondition(crossunder(close, mband), title="Close Crossunder")
```

Or more efficiently, calculate the `crossover/under` once, and use the result of it, like this:

```
a = plot(close, color = color.white, transp = 100, title = "close") 

co = crossover(close,  mband)
cu = crossunder(close, mband)

plotshape(co, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(cu, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny)

alertcondition(co, title="Close Crossover")
alertcondition(cu, title="Close Crossunder")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help